# Run Angular SPA inside Django

Tags: angularjs, django, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

We had a standalone frontend server, which just served static AngularJS files. For SEO, we want to use a service such as Prerender, and hence need to run a server which can route URLs.
We are planning to Django backend with Prerender middleware for the same(since have a server running Python).

I can serve static file for all URLs using:

```
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
                    url(r'^$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                        kwargs={'path': 'index.html',
                                'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

Now, my question is:
1- The Angular app uses local paths such for Static files, such as styles/f.css, what would be the easiest way to serve it(with routing) through Django? Any alternatives to using Django's Static keyword everywhere?
2- Django doesn't recommend serving static files directly. So, what would you use to serve the SPA through App engine(with the routing)?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use some kind of URL prefix (*STATIC_URL*) like "static" in order to clearly distinguish between requests to your Django views and your static files.

To serve your static assets you could use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/django.html).

If you really need to avoid the *STATIC_URL* prefix you can subclass or adapt [DjangoWhiteNoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise/blob/master/whitenoise/django.py) and use instead of the *STATIC_URL* prefix a set of URL prefix patterns like "css", "js" and "img"

Comment: I really don't intend to serve any Django views from this server. Just finding the easiest way to make the existing Angular app to serve from Django